# Is there a better way to plot data on a bar chart in Power Bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am working with an imported data set from Excel, for each row there is a volume for each year 2020-2030 as an individual column.

Trying to plot the sum of each column 2020-2030 in a bar chart however this does not display as expected. See attached images. Already tried adding the data to the Axis field but this does not work.

The goal is to have a plot with years 2020-2030 on X-Axis and total volume on Y-Axis, then clicking on an individual year will then filter related plots by year. So far I can only sort the data in the opposite direction clicking on a category to see the volume for a single year.

Looking for help on how to plot the data specifically and then how to link this plot to other visuals in the report.

[Bar Chart Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEYjU.png)
[Layout of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpJIp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to unpivot your data in m-query editor. Click on "transform-data". Select the table your data is on. Click the transform TAB. Select the year columns and click unpivot.

Now you get a table with many more rows wtih data like CY 2020, CY 2021 etc

You need to convert this to a number. you can do this by adding a column which picks up the 4 right chars and converts it to number:

Goto tab "Add Column", click Custom Column. Give column name and type:

```
Number.FromText(Text.End([YourColumnwiththeCY2020],4))
```

To make it even better, delete the column you had created during the unpivot. On this table you can do the graph representations..

apply and close to go back to your dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Use unpivot in PowerQuery (M) to turn the columns for each date in to a single column containing the period with values (CY-2020, CY-2021, CY-2022 etc). You can remove the CY- and turn this in to an integer column, or convert it to a date, e.g. 1/1/2020. This will plot far better on your chart as an axis as opposed to the multi values approach in you screen shots.

See a [blog post from Radacad here](https://radacad.com/pivot-and-unpivot-with-power-bi) that provides a how to.